# Find allocated size of type which holds a vec

Tags: rust

I can lookup how big a value is by calling https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.size_of_val.html. This does not work well (in my case) for `vec`'s since the size is always 32 when not dereferencing, no matter how many elements.

I added some code below, I would expect that the amount of bytes of the `Incoming` `struct` is at least as large as the bytes for variable `vec`, because the `Incoming` `struct` holds the `vec`.

Deferencing the `vec` directly when calling `size_of_val` gives me the correct size of `vec`, but I am unable to do something similar for a type that holds a `vec`.

```
use std::mem::size_of_val;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Incoming {
    Bytes(Vec<u8>),
    SomethingElse(String),
    Fixed(i64)
}

fn main() {
    let vec = vec![1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3];

    // 39
    println!("Vec's real size: {} bytes", size_of_val(&*vec));

    let incoming = Incoming::Bytes(vec);
    let size_of = size_of_val(&incoming);

    // 32
    println!("But incoming tells me it's size is {} bytes", size_of);
}
```

Is it possible to get the allocated memory for a type that holds a `vec`?

Usecase: `Incoming` represents all different requests my Rust server will handle. I want to Debug log every request. Some requests can contain `Vec<u8>` with many elements. In that case, I don't want to log that request because it literally takes minutes to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`size_of` and `size_of_val` both refer to the 'top-level' footprint of a data structure.  For instance, if you had a linked list where each node was 48 bytes, and the linked list contained one million elements, then `size_of` would only return 48, not 48 million.

There is no automatic way to calculate the total allocation size of a data structure in Rust, especially because it can be nontrivial to include amortized allocation overhead costs or calculate the size of shared, cyclic, or self-referential data structueres.

You might just want to do your own trait for the family of data structures you need.

```
trait EstimableSize {
    fn estimate_size(&self) -> usize;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When requesting `size_of_val(&*vec)`, you first [**deref**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-Deref) (`*`) `vec`, then you obtain the slice that actually contains the data, and `size_of_val()` applies to that.

If you had forgotten the `*`, then you would have obtained the size of the `Vec` struct itself, independently of the actual amount of heap-allocated data.

When it comes to `incoming` it is very similar to `vec` without the deref.

If you want the amount of heap-allocated data (as far as we are concerned, not the internal overhead), you have to *dig* into `incoming`.

```
    match incoming {
        Incoming::Bytes(ref b) => {
            let sz = size_of_val(&**b); // one deref for b, another for the Vec
            println!("bytes stored inside incoming: {}", sz);
        }
        Incoming::SomethingElse(ref t) => {
            let sz = size_of_val(&**t); // one deref for t, another for the String
            println!("text stored inside incoming: {}", sz);
        }
        Incoming::Fixed(ref f) => {
            let sz = size_of_val(&*f); // one deref for f
            println!("integer stored inside incoming: {}", sz); // no surprise here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't improve @NovaDenizen's answer: no, because `size_of_val()` is shallow. However, I thought you might like to know the allocated size of your data structure.

It depends on several things, including:

- the choice of memory allocator,
- the fragmentation of the heap,
- what context the structure is used in (e.g. is it on the stack or in the heap?),
- whether the compiler optimises any of it away.

However, with Rust's default memory allocator, if there is no fragmentation, and if you allocate a Box (and don't count the Box), you can compute the total size as follows:

- For the block containing the Incoming itself, the size is 32 bytes (`size_of_val()`) plus 8 bytes (1 word header added by the memory allocator) plus 8 bytes (pad to a multiple of 16 bytes) which makes 48 bytes.
- For the block containing the elements of the Vec, the size is 39 bytes (1 byte per element) plus 8 bytes (1 word header) plus 1 byte (pad to a multiple of 16 bytes) which makes 48 bytes.

So the answer is 96 bytes, probably, roughly.